# Oracle SQL how to convert time zone string to date

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have following `2015-06-17T00:00:00.000+05:00` string.
I want to convert this string to Date using oracle sql.
I tried lot of format mask but none works for me :

```
SELECT TO_DATE('2015-06-17T00:00:00.000+05:00','yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS TZR') FROM DUAL;
```

Any idea which format mask should i apply for above conversion.
Also please note that i only need date information i.e `(mm-dd-yyyy)`. So its also ok if the conversion results in date information only (i.e skipping time information)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT TO_DATE(SUBSTR('2015-06-17T00:00:00.000+05:00',1,10),'yyyy-mm-dd') from dual
```

Answer (score 4):

If you need to keep track of the time zone you should probably look at something like this:

```
SELECT CAST(TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('2015-06-17T00:00:00.000+05:00','yyyy-mm-dd"T"HH24:MI:SS.FFTZH:TZM') AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AS DATE) FROM DUAL;
```